# android game over screen

Tags: android, surfaceview, 2d-games

I have created this little game using `SurfaceView` and now I want to show the game over screen. Since the `SurfaceView`'s update and render methods are being called by another `Thread` I want to know how to correctly inflate the game over XML and add it to the screen.

PD: by that I mean that I know I can use a reference to the activity, and I could do

```
public void render() {
  if(gameOver) {
    View gameOverView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.gameover);
    // code to get the layout
    // and finally 
    layout.addView(gameOverView);
  }
```

but the thing is that `activity` was created in the UI thread, and `render()` is called by a secondary thread, so it throws an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You way should work if you will wrap it in runOnUiThread:

```
public void render() {
  if(gameOver)
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        View gameOverView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.gameover);
            // code to get the layout
            // and finally 
            layout.addView(gameOverView);

    }
    });
}
```

May be better to start another activity for the game over screen?

Comment: is it better than calling `public void render() {  if(gameover) activity.showGameOverScreen();  ......` ?   and have `showGameOverScreen()` display everything

Comment: It depends of your game architecture.

Comment: I'll go with your answers, seems like the proper one. By the way, should I use `synchronize`?

Answer (score 0):

SurfaceView is a View. You can just extend SurfaceView.

- Create your SurfaceView instance
- Then setContentView(Your Surface View Instance)

and you are done.

Comment: I did that, i'm actually using an extended class of SurfaceView. I created a method called update() which is called 60times per second (60FPS) which is suppose to update the entities stats, and check for gameOver. When the game is over, the game should pause and show the gameover screen.

Comment: Why don't you use onDraw method?

Comment: oh, no particular reason, I suppose I could use it.